# What do obs, ov and nv stand for in javafx listeners?

Tags: lambda, javafx, listener

Here is an example from some javafx book:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.SVGPath;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

/**
 * A login form to demonstrate lambdas, properties and bindings.
 * @author cdea
 */
public class Main extends Application {

    private final static String MY_PASS = "xyz";
    private final static BooleanProperty GRANTED_ACCESS = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    private final static int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 3;
    private final IntegerProperty ATTEMPTS = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // create a model representing a user
        User user = new User();

        // create a transparent stage
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 320, 112, Color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        // all text, borders, svg paths will use white
        Color foregroundColor = Color.rgb(255, 255, 255, .9);

        // rounded rectangular background
        Rectangle background = new Rectangle(320, 112);
        background.setX(0);
        background.setY(0);
        background.setArcHeight(15);
        background.setArcWidth(15);
        background.setFill(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0, .55));
        background.setStrokeWidth(9.5);
//        background.setStroke(foregroundColor);
        background.setStroke(Color.rgb(12, 233, 233));

        // a read only field holding the user name.
        Text userName = new Text();
        userName.setFont(Font.font("SanSerif", FontWeight.BOLD, 30));
        userName.setFill(foregroundColor);
        userName.setSmooth(true);
        userName.textProperty().bind(user.userNameProperty());

        // wrap text node
        HBox userNameCell = new HBox();
        userNameCell.prefWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.widthProperty().subtract(45));
        userNameCell.getChildren().add(userName);

        // pad lock
        SVGPath padLock = new SVGPath();
        padLock.setFill(foregroundColor);
        padLock.setContent("M24.875,15.334v-4.876c0-4.894-3.981-8.875-8.875-8.875s-8.875,3.981-8.875,8.875v4.876H5.042v15.083h21.916V15.334H24.875zM10.625,10.458c0-2.964,2.411-5.375,5.375-5.375s5.375,2.411,5.375,5.375v4.876h-10.75V10.458zM18.272,26.956h-4.545l1.222-3.667c-0.782-0.389-1.324-1.188-1.324-2.119c0-1.312,1.063-2.375,2.375-2.375s2.375,1.062,2.375,2.375c0,0.932-0.542,1.73-1.324,2.119L18.272,26.956z");

        // first row
        HBox row1 = new HBox();
        row1.getChildren().addAll(userNameCell, padLock);


        // password text field
        PasswordField passwordField = new PasswordField();
        passwordField.setFont(Font.font("SanSerif", 20));
        passwordField.setPromptText("Password");
        passwordField.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:black; "
                + "-fx-prompt-text-fill:gray; "
                + "-fx-highlight-text-fill:black; "
                + "-fx-highlight-fill: gray; "
                + "-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .80); ");
        passwordField.prefWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.widthProperty().subtract(55));
        user.passwordProperty().bind(passwordField.textProperty());

        // error icon
        SVGPath deniedIcon = new SVGPath();
        deniedIcon.setFill(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0, .9));
        deniedIcon.setStroke(Color.WHITE);//
        deniedIcon.setContent("M24.778,21.419 19.276,15.917 24.777,10.415 21.949,7.585 16.447,13.087 10.945,7.585 8.117,10.415 13.618,15.917 8.116,21.419 10.946,24.248 16.447,18.746 21.948,24.248z");
        deniedIcon.setVisible(false);

        SVGPath grantedIcon = new SVGPath();
        grantedIcon.setFill(Color.rgb(0, 255, 0, .9));
        grantedIcon.setStroke(Color.WHITE);//
        grantedIcon.setContent("M2.379,14.729 5.208,11.899 12.958,19.648 25.877,6.733 28.707,9.561 12.958,25.308z");
        grantedIcon.setVisible(false);

        StackPane accessIndicator = new StackPane();
        accessIndicator.getChildren().addAll(deniedIcon, grantedIcon);
        accessIndicator.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

        grantedIcon.visibleProperty().bind(GRANTED_ACCESS);

        // second row
        HBox row2 = new HBox(3);
        row2.getChildren().addAll(passwordField, accessIndicator);
        HBox.setHgrow(accessIndicator, Priority.ALWAYS);

        // user hits the enter key
        passwordField.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            if (GRANTED_ACCESS.get()) {
                System.out.printf("User %s is granted access.\n", user.getUserName());
                System.out.printf("User %s entered the password: %s\n", user.getUserName(), user.getPassword());
                Platform.exit();
            } else {
                deniedIcon.setVisible(true);
            }
            ATTEMPTS.set(ATTEMPTS.add(1).get());
            System.out.println("Attempts: " + ATTEMPTS.get());
        });

        // listener when the user types into the password field
        passwordField.textProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
            boolean granted = passwordField.getText().equals(MY_PASS);
            GRANTED_ACCESS.set(granted);
            if (granted) {
                deniedIcon.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        // listener on number of attempts
        ATTEMPTS.addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
            if (MAX_ATTEMPTS == nv.intValue()) {
                // failed attemps
                System.out.printf("User %s is denied access.\n", user.getUserName());
                Platform.exit();
            }
        });

        VBox formLayout = new VBox(4);
        formLayout.getChildren().addAll(row1, row2);
        formLayout.setLayoutX(12);
        formLayout.setLayoutY(12);

        root.getChildren().addAll(background, formLayout);

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I don't quite understand these two listeners:

```
    // listener when the user types into the password field
    passwordField.textProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
        boolean granted = passwordField.getText().equals(MY_PASS);
        GRANTED_ACCESS.set(granted);
        if (granted) {
            deniedIcon.setVisible(false);
        }
    });

    // listener on number of attempts
    ATTEMPTS.addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
        if (MAX_ATTEMPTS == nv.intValue()) {
            // failed attemps
            System.out.printf("User %s is denied access.\n", user.getUserName());
            Platform.exit();
        }
    });
```

In the first listener none of obs, ov or nv are used, in the second, only nv is used. What are obs, ov and nv exactly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html

`changed(ObservableValue<? extends T> observable, T oldValue, T newValue)`

It's because when using lambdas you don't have to provide the types.  If you're keyboarding it out manually, then it's easier to use obs, ov, nv.  In just about any changeListener I've written, I only usually access the newValue - nv.

The code example could be changed

`boolean granted = passwordField.getText().equals(MY_PASS);`

could be

`boolean granted = nv.equals(MY_PASS);`

Answer (score 0):

Glad you're reading this book, by the way!

As it states at the beginning of chapter 3, the new language feature introduced in Java 8 called *lambda expressions*, or just *lambdas*, allows you to avoid the use of anonymous inner classes like this:

```
passwordField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        boolean granted = passwordField.getText().equals(MY_PASS);
        GRANTED_ACCESS.set(granted);
        if (granted) {
            deniedIcon.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
});
```

by using an expression like this:

```
passwordField.textProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) -> {
    boolean granted = passwordField.getText().equals(MY_PASS);
    GRANTED_ACCESS.set(granted);
    if (granted) {
        deniedIcon.setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

Besides, parameters can be optionally typed. The compiler will infer the type
of the parameters depending on the context, by matching the method’s argument types (its signature) and its return type. And because of this, as in the inner class, we have to use all the parameters required, even they are not used in the body of your function.

So we can also write:

```
passwordField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    boolean granted = passwordField.getText().equals(MY_PASS);
    GRANTED_ACCESS.set(granted);
    if (granted) {
        deniedIcon.setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

Finally, as @brian says, the name you give to the parameter is arbitrary, and we can simplify it for convenience:

```
passwordField.textProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
    boolean granted = passwordField.getText().equals(MY_PASS);
    GRANTED_ACCESS.set(granted);
    if (granted) {
        deniedIcon.setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

He is right too about using `nv`:

```
passwordField.textProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
    boolean granted = nv.equals(MY_PASS);
    GRANTED_ACCESS.set(granted);
    if (granted) {
        deniedIcon.setVisible(false);
    }
});
```